# pandasでログデータに対してセッションIDを付与したい

Tags: python, pandas

以下のようなログデータに対してpandasでセッションIDを付与したいのですがやり方がわかりません。

```
user time 
0    2020-05-23 00:01:19
0    2020-05-23 00:13:32
1    2020-05-23 00:13:45
0    2020-05-23 12:59:45
2    2020-05-23 13:13:13
1    2020-05-23 15:13:45
```

userはユーザを識別するための一意なID、timeはユーザーがアクセスした時間を表します。
同じユーザーの6時間以内のアクセスであれば同じセッションIDが割り振られます。
ユーザーが異なればセッションIDも異なります。

そのため上記の例を補完すると以下のようになります。

```
user time                 session_id
0    2020-05-23 00:01:19  0
0    2020-05-23 00:13:32  0
1    2020-05-23 00:13:45  1
0    2020-05-23 12:59:45  2
2    2020-05-23 13:13:13  3
1    2020-05-23 15:13:45  4
```

教えていただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: もう少し条件を明確化しましょう。例えば同じユーザーが5時間毎に記録された場合、それぞれの間は6時間経っていないけれども、最初から10時間経った3件目のIDは同じですか変わりますか？ それからIDの割り振りは時刻順の必要がありますか？例えばユーザー0の記録に順番に割り振って10までいった後、時系列的には戻ったユーザー1の最初の記録へ次の11から割り振るといったことが出来ますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。最後の記録から6時間経っていれば異なるIDが割り振られるのでご提示いただいた例(5時間+5時間)では同じIDです。時刻順である必要はないのでその例ではユーザー1の最初の記録に11を割り振ることができます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一応、[本家の方で解決](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67948917)となった様ですが、、、

どうも `freq='6H'` という指定に問題がありそうです。

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'user': [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1],
  'time': map(pd.Timestamp, [
            '2020-05-23 00:01:19',
            '2020-05-23 00:13:32',
            '2020-05-23 00:13:45',
            '2020-05-23 06:10:45', 
            '2020-05-23 13:13:13',
            '2020-05-23 15:13:45',
          ]),
})

df['session_id'] = (
  df.groupby(['user', pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='6H')], sort=False)
    .ngroup())

print(df)

## 処理結果
   user                time  session_id
0     0 2020-05-23 00:01:19           0
1     0 2020-05-23 00:13:32           0  <== user 0
2     1 2020-05-23 00:13:45           1
3     0 2020-05-23 06:10:45           2  <== user 0
4     2 2020-05-23 13:13:13           3
5     1 2020-05-23 15:13:45           4
```

3 行目の session_id が `2` になっています。前回の session は `00:13:32` なので 6 時間以内のはずです。

それでは「6 時間以内の差」でグループ化してみます。

```py
s = df.sort_values(['user', 'time']).groupby('user').time.diff()\
      .gt(pd.Timedelta('6h')).cumsum().sort_index()

df['session_id'] = df.groupby(['user', s], sort=False).ngroup()

print(df)

## 処理結果
   user                time  session_id
0     0 2020-05-23 00:01:19           0
1     0 2020-05-23 00:13:32           0 <== user 0
2     1 2020-05-23 00:13:45           1
3     0 2020-05-23 06:10:45           0 <== user 0
4     2 2020-05-23 13:13:13           2
5     1 2020-05-23 15:13:45           3
```

こちらでは 3 行目の session_id が `0` になります。

つまり、`freq='6H'` は一日を `00:00〜06:00`, `06:00〜12:00`, `12:00〜18:00`, `18:00〜24:00` で区切ってグループ化するという事なのでした。

なお、この処理方法は以下を参考に(というかコピペ)しました。

[How to assign a unique ID for different groups in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978362)

Comment: すごい！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

コメントで確認したのは、以下のような処理を考えていたためです。
最初に`user`を主キー、`time`を副キーとしてソートしておき、あとはループで順次直前の行と比較して`session_id`を埋めていく方法です。
最後は`time`でソートし直します。`session_id`は質問例のような時刻順にはなっていません。

```
# 初期化処理は metropolis さん回答からコピー
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'user': [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1],
  'time': map(pd.Timestamp, [
          '2020-05-23 00:01:19',
          '2020-05-23 00:13:32',
          '2020-05-23 00:13:45',
          '2020-05-23 12:59:45',
          '2020-05-23 13:13:13',
          '2020-05-23 15:13:45',
        ]),
})

df = df.sort_values(['user','time'],ascending=[True,True]) # userを主キー、timeを副キーでソート
df['session_id'] = None                                    # session_id列追加
id_index = list(df.columns.values).index('session_id')     # session_idの列番号取得

session_timeout = 6 * 60 * 60 # 6時間の秒数
session_id = 0                # session_id初期値

df.iat[0, id_index] = session_id
prev = df.iloc[0]
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    curr = df.iloc[i]
    # userが変わるか、前回より6時間経過していたら新しいsession_id
    if prev.user != curr.user or (curr.time - prev.time).total_seconds() > session_timeout:
        session_id += 1
    df.iat[i, id_index] = session_id # session_id設定
    prev = curr

df = df.sort_values('time',ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True) # timeでソート、indexも振り直し
print(df)

# 以下が実行結果
   user                time session_id
0     0 2020-05-23 00:01:19          0
1     0 2020-05-23 00:13:32          0
2     1 2020-05-23 00:13:45          2
3     0 2020-05-23 12:59:45          1
4     2 2020-05-23 13:13:13          4
5     1 2020-05-23 15:13:45          3
```